# Convert very large Xml file to Json file using Python in aws glue

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-glue

I am trying to convert very large xml files which are placed in my S3 bucket to Json file.

For smaller files upto 300 mb i am able to convert successfully using ‘xmltodict’. Although for larger files 1-5 gbs I am getting memory issues.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried some solutions using xml.etree and xml.sax but everytime i keep facing some issue.

Can I please get some working code that will be able to process large xml files.

Do Note that the xml structure is quite complex and has multiple child tags inside parent tags in xml.